# object file being sent instead of file information while trying to upload file through http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Trying to upload a file through Angular $http. I am setting the Content-Type and wrapping it up with the FormData object as advised in most places. However the browser sends [object data] in the request payload of the http request.

Service making call:

```
let fd = new FormData();

            fd.append('file', file);
            return $q((resolve, reject) => {
                $http.post(url, fd, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined,
                        'X-Token': undefined
                    }
                }).then(
                        success => resolve(success.data),
                        error => reject(error)
                    );
            });
```

Thoughts on why the browser is not able to encode this file? Note that i have tried a docx, zip, mp4 file formats so far. They all yield the same result.

Request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqfOlKmKqvArA9pz6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

[object File]
------WebKitFormBoundaryqfOlKmKqvArA9pz6--
```

Markup used:

```
<input type="file" id="file-tutorial-{{$index}}-{{language.iso2}}" name="file-tutorial-{{$index}}-{{language.iso2}}"
                                     onchange="angular.element(this).scope().ctrl.addFile(this);">
```

Ctrl.addFile:

```
addFile(element) {
    service.uploadFile(element.files[0]);
    this.$scope.$digest();
}
```

element.files[0] or the file object:

```
{lastModified:1496720186000
 lastModifiedDate:Mon Jun 05 2017 23:36:26 GMT-0400 (EDT)
 name:"Adil Sulaiman Resume.docx"
 size:25456
 type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-
 officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
 webkitRelativePath:""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are missing `angular.identity`, that prevents Angular to do anything on the file you are sending, e.g. serialize it. See an explanation [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/283119)

Your are using the native `onchange` event, which is outside of angular scope. Have a look at this [article](https://www.uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs/) for how to gain access to the file object.

Working demo can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yvq7sXu4uibRoo66le4i?p=preview)

Comment: Tried that as well but no dice.

Comment: are you using ng-model with input[type=file] ?

Comment: I've added a demo that shows a working example, the actual post will not work but you will see that [Object object] is not present in the request